# Apache Beam - pip install '.[gcp,test]' - RuntimeError: Not in apache git tree; unable to find proto definitions

Tags: python-2.7, sdk, apache-beam

I'm trying to follow the Apache Beam Contribution Guide [Developing with the Python SDK](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/#developing-with-the-python-sdk)

Using Python 2.7.15
Steps:

1. git clone git@github.com:apache/beam.git
2. Create a new virtual env (--no-side-packages )
3. pip install cython
4. ran `pip install '.[gcp,test]'`  on this sdks/python directory

output:

```
pip install '.[gcp,test]' 
    Processing /Users/jcc/beam/sdks/python
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Compiling apache_beam/coders/stream.pyx because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/runners/worker/statesampler_fast.pyx because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/transforms/cy_dataflow_distribution_counter.pyx because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/metrics/execution.py because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/runners/common.py because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/runners/worker/logger.py because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/transforms/cy_combiners.py because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/utils/counters.py because it changed.
    Compiling apache_beam/utils/windowed_value.py because it changed.
    [ 1/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py
    [ 2/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/coders/stream.pyx
    [ 3/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/metrics/execution.py
    [ 4/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/runners/common.py
    [ 5/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/runners/worker/logger.py
    [ 6/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py
    [ 7/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py
    [ 8/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/runners/worker/statesampler_fast.pyx
    [ 9/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/transforms/cy_combiners.py
    [10/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/transforms/cy_dataflow_distribution_counter.pyx
    [11/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/utils/counters.py
    [12/12] Cythonizing apache_beam/utils/windowed_value.py
    /Users/h4rry/env_beam/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:398: UserWarning: Normalizing '2.7.0.dev' to '2.7.0.dev0'
    normalized_version,
    running egg_info
    /private/var/folders/k9/6y5rqvq91fv360rq0p271mkr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-YZpmvt/../common
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/k9/6y5rqvq91fv360rq0p271mkr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-YZpmvt/setup.py", line 218, in <module>
        'test': generate_protos_first(test),
    File "/Users/h4rry/env_beam/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 131, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/k9/6y5rqvq91fv360rq0p271mkr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-YZpmvt/setup.py", line 152, in run
        gen_protos.generate_proto_files()
    File "gen_protos.py", line 68, in generate_proto_files
        'Not in apache git tree; unable to find proto definitions.')
    RuntimeError: Not in apache git tree; unable to find proto definitions.

    ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/k9/6y5rqvq91fv360rq0p271mkr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-YZpmvt/
```

---

File "gen_protos.py" in line 68:

```
if not os.path.exists(common):
        raise RuntimeError(
            'Not in apache git tree; unable to find proto definitions.')
```

---

it's failing because this path doesn't exist:

**common** at that time is:

/private/var/folders/k9/6y5rqvq91fv360rq0p271mkr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-YZpmvt/../common

I'm pretty new to beam, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are installing Apache Beam from source, you'll want to install with `-e` flag passed in, to install in 'editable' mode.:

`pip install -e .[gcp,test]`